# C++ Class inheritance and templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I would like to write in my C++ program something like:

```
class A {
 public:
   void a();
}

template <class B extends A>
class C {
 B instance;
}
```

Is this possible? In other words: does C++ allow me to say that the class within a template is a subclass of something else?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: similar, but that one is about functions and this is about classes.  The solutions can be slightly different (e.g. enable_if is the top answer there, but doesn't make as much sense here).

Answer (score 5):

Define a meta-function called `extends` (which is just a sugar-coated name) as:

```
template<typename D, typename B>
using extends = std::is_base_of<B,D>;
```

Then define your class as:

```
template <class B>
class C 
{
   //here you can check it, and generate your own error message!
   static_assert(extends<B,A>(), 
                "Constraint Violation: B doesn't derive from A.");

   B instance;
};
```

Or, you can write this instead:

```
//define it a bit differently now!
template<typename D, typename B>
using extends = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B,D>::value>::type;

template <class B, class Unused=extends<B,A>>
class C 
{
      B instance;
};
```

But in this case, you don't have opportunity to generate your own error message. The compiler is free to throw *any error message* at you which may be difficult to comprehend.

Anyway, you probably realize you can use `std::is_base_of<>` directly. But if you're looking for sugar-coated *name*, then `extends` sounds good!

Comment: you can remove `Unused` from the 2nd example

Answer (score 4):

Not really in a direct way.  But you can use [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) with [type_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_base_of/), like this:

```
static_assert(is_base_of<A,B>::value, "C<B> requires B:A");
```

You can put that in your constructor for example, then it will fail to compile if the requirement is not satisfied.  Note that this is all C++11 stuff, but it exists in Boost long before that, or you can code it up yourself if you're really stuck (it doesn't require language support).